# Prestashop profiler directory inside app/cache/dev too big

Tags: prestashop

app/cache/dev/profiler is 1.4 Gb in size! What is this for? Is it necessary for prestashop to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is cache file, it is saved when you set for your site is cached, you can manual remove it or go to backend >> Advance Parameters >> Perfomance => click to **clear cache** button on top bar.

Answer (score 0):

An extra info on all this:

Let me explain. If you have, for example, a lot of cache stored at /dev/cache/profiler and you try to clear the cache but the Debug Mode is "OFF" then it will not work at all. Try to turn on the Debug Mode "ON" and then clear the cache.

This is just for front-end users. You can just delete the whole files from the server instead if you have access.